# android 12 latest release: Emulator build not running for android-12.0.0_r2 aosp release

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-12

I have built android-12.0.0_r2 locally and trying to run it but it is giving error.

Build steps:

$ source build/envsetup.sh

$ lunch aosp_x86_64-eng

$ make -j32

Run:

$ emulator &

Error:
out/target/product/generic_arm64/userdata-qemu.img': No such file or directory

Even after copying this image from android_11, I can see emulator starting but It is in hanging state.
Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me.

1. Apply below change on `platform/build/make`.

   ```
   diff --git a/target/product/AndroidProducts.mk b/target/product/AndroidProducts.mk
   index 7d9d90e..419cccb 100644
   --- a/target/product/AndroidProducts.mk
   +++ b/target/product/AndroidProducts.mk
   @@ -84,3 +84,4 @@ COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES := \
        aosp_arm-eng \
        aosp_x86_64-eng \
        aosp_x86-eng \
   +    sdk_phone_x86_64-eng \
   ```
2. `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-eng`

Comment: I tested this on android-13.0.0_r8 and this worked, Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think that

***userdata-qemu.img*** Rename to ***userdata_qemu.img***

then maybe your problem will be solved

Comment: Thanx for your comment. I don't see this image at all in android 12 build setup. I used same steps for building android 11 and it is working.