# qemu-system-aarch64: Could not open '..../userdata-qemu.img': No such file or directory

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

Trying to get AOSP 12L to build and run on my computer but when I try to run the 'emulator' cmd I get:

```
emulator
emulator: Android emulator version 30.9.0.0 (build_id 7651928) (CL:N/A)
2023-08-01 23:26:51.921 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering beacon_swarm
2023-08-01 23:26:51.921 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering beacon
2023-08-01 23:26:51.921 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering scripted_beacon
2023-08-01 23:26:51.922 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering remote_loopback
2023-08-01 23:26:51.922 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering car_kit
2023-08-01 23:26:51.922 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering classic
2023-08-01 23:26:51.922 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering sniffer
2023-08-01 23:26:51.922 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering keyboard
emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
cannot add library /home/grant/aosp/pixel3a/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library /home/grant/aosp/pixel3a/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
qemu-system-aarch64: Could not open '/home/grant/aosp/pixel3a/out/target/product/sargo/userdata-qemu.img': No such file or directory
```

Steps to I took:

```
cd aosp/pixel3a          # where Im holding everything
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_sargo-userdebug
m droid -j16
rm out/target/product/sargo/*.lock            # for some reason I have to do this before running the emulator sometimes or it just says there is one running already.
emulator
```

I checked

```
/home/grant/aosp/pixel3a/out/target/product/sargo/
```

and

```
userdata-qemu.img
```

is indeed not there.
I saw this post [on how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553871/android-12-latest-release-emulator-build-not-running-for-android-12-0-0-r2-aosp#:%7E:text=userdata%2Dqemu.img%20Rename%20to%20userdata_qemu.img) but I dont have "userdata_qemu.img" either.